# Delete rows when specific condition found

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete rows which matches below condition.

I have excel workbook in that a sheet named "Calls closed"
in column "I" drop down list there are  many conditions in that I want delete all row which matches below condition.

"Closed by bank", "With Requestor For Closure" ,"Abandoned by Requestor"

I tried below code its not working for me

```
 Sub Callsclosed_DeleteRow()

 "Closed by bank", "With Requestor For Closure" ,"Abandoned by Requestor"

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim wrksht As Excel.Worksheet

Set wrksht = Application.Worksheets("Calls closed")

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 20000 Step -1
    If IsError(Application.Match(Range("L" & i).Value, Array("Closed By Bank", "With Requestor For Closure", "Abandoned by Requestor"), 0)) Then
 Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete all matches to the array, you need to look for `If Not IsError(Application.Match...` , that means that the current's cell value is found within the array.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Callsclosed_DeleteRow()
' "Closed by bank", "With Requestor For Closure" ,"Abandoned by Requestor"

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim WrkSht As Excel.Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WrkSht = Application.Worksheets("Calls closed")
With WrkSht
    LR = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("L" & i).Value, Array("Closed By Bank", "With Requestor For Closure", "Abandoned by Requestor"), 0)) Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ... i want to select rows from 1 to 20000 because my data doesn't cross 20000 rows ...or is there any dynamic way to find the last row and search from there and keep deleting all matches from bottom to top..

Comment: @Kittu try the code now, you are looking on column L, right ?

Comment: Yes L column .....Perfect....i think we need to change here too  LR = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   ..."A" TO "L"

Comment: its my pleasure... but i am not able to find check mark next to your answer..??

Comment: @Kittu  on the left side, it's grey now